# JavaScript String split()

Tags: javascript, string, split

We have multiple records, each record has an asset list. The assest list consists of multiple client names and sites (name-site, name-site_2, name2-site_3, name3-site_4).

I'm trying to split the asset list to end up with two lists, one of all of the names and one of all of the sites (I only want to show what's unique in each list). I'm splitting at the comma and then split again at the hyphen

What I've created below works, but recently I've encountered some client-site combos that have an extra hyphen, which breaks my solution (I initially split the string by comma and then split the substrings by hyphen). To add another wrinkle, the extra hyphen is not always in the same spot, depending on the category it could be the first hyphen (in the client name) or second hyphen (in the site) that needs to be ignored, fortunately, this is consistent by category (if category == "animals").

For category animals if there are two hyphens I need to ignore the first.

For category fruit if there are two hyphens I need to ignore the second.

Any ideas?

Example asset lists:
category == "animals"
if there is two hyphens, I need to split at the second.
assetList ="fish-mark, cat-jim, blue-dog-henry, red-bird-bill, green-snake-larry"

category == "fruit"
if there is two hyphens, I need to split at the first.
assetList = "lime-henry, lemon-susan, banana-bob-nelson, apple-rick-jones, pineapple-sam-smith"

Below is my code:

```
var assetList = "fish-mark, cat-jim, blue-dog-henry, red-bird-bill, green-snake-larry";

var count = (assetList.match(/-/g) || []).length;//counts the hyphens (client-siteId combo)

var splitObj = {};
var comboObj = {};
var clientObj = {};
var siteObj = {};
var mainSplitObj = {};
var allClient = '';
var allSite = '';

mainSplitObj = assetList.split(', ');

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        splitObj["split"+i] = mainSplitObj[0+i]; //puts the client-siteID into a substring
            comboObj["combo"+i] = splitObj["split"+i].split('-'); //splits the client-siteID at the dash
                clientObj["client"+i] = comboObj["combo"+i][0]; //puts the client name in a substring
                siteObj["site"+i] = comboObj["combo"+i][1]; //puts the siteid in a substring

                    allClient += clientObj["client"+i] +";"+ ' '; //cumulatively adds client substrings to allClient variable
                    allSite += siteObj["site"+i] +";" + ' '; //cumulatively adds site substrings to allSite variable

    }

        tempC = allClient.split(",")
        uniqueClient = []
            for (var i = 0; i < tempC.length; i++) {
                isIn = 0
                for (var j = 0; j < uniqueClient.length; j++) {
                    if (tempC[i] == uniqueClient[j]) {
                        isIn = 1
                    }
                }
                if (isIn == 0) {
                    uniqueClient.push(tempC[i])
                }
            }
        tempS = allSite.split(",")
        uniqueSite = []
            for (var i = 0; i < tempS.length; i++) {
                isIn = 0
                for (var j = 0; j < uniqueSite.length; j++) {
                    if (tempS[i] == uniqueSite[j]) {
                        isIn = 1
                    }
                }
                if (isIn == 0) {
                    uniqueSite.push(tempS[i])
                }
            }
```

Comment: do not use split - use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` (in combination with `substring`) depending on the category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do at with indexOf and lastIndexOf. It splits on the last instead of the second hyphen which in your case gives you the same results.

```
// Split on first hyphen
var list = ["lime-henry", "lemon-susan", "banana-bob-nelson", "apple-rick-jones", "pineapple-sam-smith"];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var delimiterIndex = list[i].indexOf("-");
    var item = list[i];
    var left = item.substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    var right = item.substring(delimiterIndex + 1, item.length);
    console.log(left, right);
  }

  /* outputs
   * lime henry
   * lemon susan
   * banana bob-nelson
   * apple rick-jones
   * pineapple sam-smith
  */

// Split on last hyphen
var list = ["fish-mark", "cat-jim", "blue-dog-henry", "red-bird-bill", "green-snake-larry"];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var delimiterIndex = list[i].lastIndexOf("-");
    var item = list[i];
    var left = item.substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    var right = item.substring(delimiterIndex + 1, item.length);
    console.log(left, right);
  }

  /* outputs
   * fish mark
   * cat jim
   * blue-dog henry
   * red-bird bill
   * green-snake larry
   */
```